# Disable JavaScript in IE 11 preview

Tags: internet-explorer

Ok, I feel a little silly, but in earlier F12 tools, there was a disable menu where we could disable JavaScript.

Where is that functionality in the F12 tools for the IE 11 preview?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can disable JavaScript from:

Tools (Alt+x) > Internet Options > Security > Custom Level > (in the tree view) Scripting > Active Scripting > Disable (radio button)

This will disable script for the current zone. You'll want to refresh the page for it to have an impact and then re-enable it after your done.

Comment: I was hoping this wasn't the answer, but seeing no other options myself, I'd have to agree.  Thanks.

Comment: I agree - this is functionality that I use a lot when I'm testing my websites to make sure I'm handling scenarios where users have their javascript turned off.  Having to go into internet options and turn it off/on that way is too cumbersome.  I wish/hope they add that back to the developer tools.

Comment: I want the old F12 tools back :( this is enough to take me back to Firefox with Firebug. Just when IE tools where closing the gap on its competitors.

Comment: another reason to cry about ie

Comment: F12 doesn't give me a way to disable

Comment: Change Security Zone for this level to High. Slightly easier than finding the Active Scripting item in the tree view in Custom Level.

Comment: In my case (working in Sitecore), I found that this method didn't work (got an in infinite load). Choosing 'prompt' also wasn't good - got infinite prompts (you press don't allow, the same popup reappears after). IE....ugh. Thx for your answer though - its technically correct and maybe works better outside of certain CMS