# confirmation dialog cancel button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, browser

i Have button that shows confirmation dialog

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSignOff" runat="server" 
    CssClass="button" Text="Sign OFF"
    OnClick="btnSignOff_Click"
    OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Sign OFF?');"  
/>
```

the problem is even i clicked the cancel button, the page will reload and execute the server side code instead of nothing happen.

note: Were using INTERNET EXPLORER browser.

Weird scenario is when i tried to some client's machine with same browser it works fine.
but in other client's machine its not working.

how can i check the accuracy of this code if some clients scenario is not working.

thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619395/onclick-not-working-when-i-use-both-onclick-onclientclick

Comment: I solved this issue using the ajax tool kit extender

Answer (score 0):

```
OnClientClick="if(confirm('Are you sure you want to Sign OFF?')) return true; else return false;"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Confirm1() {
            return confirm("Are you sure you want to Sign OFF?");
        }
    </script>

<asp:Button ID="btnSignOff" runat="server" 
    CssClass="button" Text="Sign OFF"
    OnClick="btnSignOff_Click"
    OnClientClick="return Confirm1()"
/>
```

works 100%

Answer (score 0):

*"Weird scenario is when i tried to some client's machine with same browser it works fine. but in other client's machine its not working."*

Probably scripts are disabled in browser. make sure active script is enabled

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089298/disable-javascript-in-ie-11-preview)